# express 4.x bodyparser isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I installed latest version of body-parser(1.17.1) and set my code in proper order as others suggested.

1. import express
2. import body-parser
3. app = express();
4. app.use(bodyParser.json());
5. app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));

but I constantly get error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined".

Actually I can't imagine what the problem is.

I spent almost 10 hours keep tracking solution and I'm almost given up.

Is there any method to get my code work?

Help me some, please...

below is my code

```
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const session = require('express-session');
    const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const passport = require('passport');
    const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    const pbkdf2Password = require('pbkdf2-password');
    const hasher = pbkdf2Password();
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '10rhrnak',
    database: 'users',
    });
    connection.connect();

    //crawler setting
    const http = require('http');
    const cheerio = require('cheerio');
    const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || '4200';
    app.set('port', port);
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
    });

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(session({
    secret: '@232t2g23',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MySQLStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: '10rhrnak',
        database: 'users',
    })
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    app.post('/auth/register', (res, req) => {

        hasher({password: req.body.password}, (err, pass, salt, hash) => {
            let user = {
                authId: 'local'+req.body.email,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hash,
                salt: salt,
                displayName: req.body.displayName
            };
            let sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET ?';
            connection.query(sql, user, (err, results) => {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    throw new Error("register error!");
                } else {
                    req.redirect('/');
                }
            });
        });   
    });
```

and also my front end code(angular2 html template)

```
<div class="loginbox">
  <div [hidden]="submitted">
    <header>MAILBOY</header>
    <form ngNoForm action="/auth/register" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="이메일 주소"/>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="비밀번호"/>
      <input type="text" name="displayName" id="displayName" placeholder="사용자 이름"/>
      <button type="submit" class="login">가입</button>
    </form>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: How are you testing this route?

Comment: How do you send the data? Is  it in request body or query  string?

Comment: I have an angular2 template for front end

This is angular2 html template file

<div class="loginbox">

  <div [hidden]="submitted">

    <header>MAILBOY</header>

    <form ngNoForm action="/auth/register" method="post">

      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="이메일 주소"/>

      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="비밀번호"/>

      <input type="text" name="nickName" id="nickname" placeholder="사용자 이름"/>

      <button type="submit" class="login">가입</button>
    </form>
  </div> 
</div>

Comment: and I send my data thru input form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You switched the arguments for the route handler:

```
app.post('/auth/register', (res, req) => { ... });
```

That should be:

```
app.post('/auth/register', (req, res) => { ... });
```